# Unity3D GenerateManifest.cs

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest, manifest

Unity documentation (https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/Manual/android-BuildProcess.html) said:

> Permissions automatically added to the build manifest
>
> Unity automatically adds certain permissions to the manifest. The
>   logic is defined in the file
>   PlatformDependent/AndroidPlayer/Editor/Managed/PostProcessor/Tasks/GenerateManifest.cs
>   :: SetPermissionAttributes. For example, if your script code
>   references Application.internetReachability, Unity automatically adds
>   android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE to the manifest. You can edit
>   GenerateManifest.cs to remove it.

Where I can find this GenerateManifest.cs to edit?

Answer (score 2):

There is an XML file that you can see permissions for android.
To access this file first you should Build your project for android,then go to "...yourProjectPath\Temp\StagingArea" and open "AndroidManifest.xml" .

Comment: This is probably not true to Unity3D, I'm not using Android Studio

Comment: @DiegoPratesdeAndrade I saw what you are referring to, and my research leads me here. It seems we can only do what Behnam suggests, that is copy the AndroidManifest.xml from Temp/StagingArea into Assets/Plugins/Android and tweak it there.